# How to insert multiple records into database at a time by ajax in ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to save records in two models where one model can get single row and second model can get multiple rows. Please help me to resolve it.

Controller: PatientTestsController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddPatientTest(PatientTestsAndBilling ptb)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }

        return View(ptb);
}
```

Model : PatientTest

```
public class PatientTest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Patient Id")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Test Id")]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Center")]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    //relation of Tests table
    public virtual Tests Tests { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    //relation of Doctors table
    public virtual Doctors Doctors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Center Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("CenterId")]
    //relation of Centers table
    public virtual Centers Centers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Patient")]
    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    //relation of Patient table
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

Model : PatientBilling

```
public class PatientTest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Patient Id")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Test Id")]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Center")]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    //relation of Tests table
    public virtual Tests Tests { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    //relation of Doctors table
    public virtual Doctors Doctors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Center Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("CenterId")]
    //relation of Centers table
    public virtual Centers Centers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Patient")]
    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    //relation of Patient table
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

Model : PatientTestAndBilling

```
public class PatientTestsAndBilling
{
    public List<PatientTest> patientTests { get; set; }
    public PatientBilling patientBilling { get; set; }
}
```

This is my jQuery code..

```
 $("#save").click(function () {
        var row = $('#table2 tbody tr').length;
        var patientTest=[];
        var patientBilling;
        var j;
        for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            j = i + 1;
            patientTest.push({
                PatientId: $('#patientId').val(),
                TestId: $('#table2 tbody tr:nth-child('+j+')').attr('id'),
                DoctorId: $('#doctor').val(),
                CenterId: $('#center').val(),

            });
        }
        patientBilling= {
                PatientId: $('#patientId').val(),
                TotalPrice: $('#total_price').text(),
                PaidAmt: $('#total_paid').text(),
                BalanceAmt: $('#balance').text(),
                OtherCharges: $('#ot_charges').val(),
                Discount: $('#discount').val(),
                PaymentType: $('#payType').val()
        };
        var model = {
            "patientTest": patientTest,
            "patientBilling": patientBilling
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(model));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Reception/PatientTests/AddPatientTest",
            data: model,
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

In this example, I am getting only Patient Billing data not Patient test data.

Please help me to resolve it..

Comment: I the model you are creating inside the ajax call, the name of the variable is "patientTest", could you try making it "patientTests" ?

Comment: thank u Shariful bhai..

Comment: it's resolved but have one more issue not getting TestId value in controller model PatientTest

Comment: Are you sure that the json data contains the TestId?

Comment: Yes it's contained and ajax post that data bot in contoller getting 0(zero)

Comment: can you share the json that you are getting?

Comment: It's posted here on top

Comment: can you help me one more time? I am unable to get data from both tables PatientTest and PatientBilling by entity framework code first approach

Comment: You mean get the data from db?

Comment: yes, and you can see table model here above

Comment: how are you getting the data? can you share the method?